# What is the correct way to send a JSON POST and header with Guzzle 7?

Tags: laravel, guzzle6, guzzle

I need to send this body as JSON, using that header to authenticate.

```
$headers = array( 
    'Authorization' => "Bearer ".$token->access_token,
    'Content-Type' => 'application/json',
);

$body = [ 
    'code1' => '444444',
    'code2' => 'zzzzz'
];
```

Firts approach, this code does not work:

```
 $myhttp = new Client();

 $res = $myhttp->request('POST', 'https://www.xxxxxxxxxxxx',
     [
         'headers' => ['Content-Type' => 'application/json',"Authorization" => "Bearer ".$token->access_token],
         'json' => ['code1' => '444444','code2' => 'zzzz']
     ]
 );
```

Second approach neither:

```
$body= json_encode($body);

$res = $myhttp->request('POST', 'https://www.xxxxxxxxxxxx',
    [
        'headers' => ['Content-Type' => 'application/json',"Authorization" => "Bearer ".$token->access_token],
        'body' => $body]
    ]
);
```

Third approach neither:
When trying to use body, Guzzle tells me that this is deprecated and now `"form_params"` is used, but form_params accepts only arrays, not json.

```
$body= json_encode($body); // encode to json!

$res = $myhttp->request('POST', 'https://www.xxxxxxxxxxxx',
    [
        'headers' => ['Content-Type' => 'application/json',"Authorization" => "Bearer ".$token->access_token],
        'form_params' => $body]
    ]
);
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to use `GuzzleHttp\RequestOptions::JSON` from Guzzle :

```
$client = new Client();

$response = $client->post('https://www.xxxxxxxxxxxx', [
    GuzzleHttp\RequestOptions::JSON => ['code1' => '444444','code2' => 'zzzz']
]);
```

Comment: GuzzleHttp\RequestOptions' not found ... trying to solve.

Comment: I did a fresh install of laravel and guzzle 7, and the same, GuzzleHttp \ RequestOptions' not found...ufff

Comment: @rendor9 reload all class `composer dump-autoload`

Comment: I do composer dump-autoload, the answer is GuzzleHttp\RequestOptions' not found